# Append string to existing record with matching id in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a table where I want to append name column if id1 and id2 column have same values.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8be48/1

Input table

```
id1 id2 name
1   1   a
1   1   b
2   2   c
2   2   c
3   3   d
3   3   e
3   3   f
```

Expected Output

```
id1 id2 name
1   1   a | b
2   2   c | c
3   3   d | e | f
```

I tried groping the id1 and id2 together and concatenating name column but it didn't work out.

```
select id1, id2, name + ' | ' + name
from testdata
group by id1, id2;
```

Comment: Why id1 and id2 have the same values? Perhaps your sample should also have a (2,3, 'g') and a (2,3,'h') tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use STUFF String function :

CREATE TABLE #table(id1 INT, id2 INT , name VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #table(id1 , id2 ,name )
SELECT 1,1,'a' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,'b' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,'c' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,'c' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,3,'d' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,3,'e' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,3,'f' 

SELECT T1.id1 id1, T1.id2 id2 , STUFF( ( SELECT ' | ' + name FROM #table T2   
WHERE T1.id1 = T2.id1 AND T1.id2 = T2.id2 FOR XML PATH('') ) ,1,2,'') 
FROM #table T1
GROUP BY id1 , id2
```

Comment: @user614978 , I posted answer for your question.Try that query.

Comment: You might want to add `AND T1.id2 = T2.id2` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Giorgos Altanis,Thanks for your comments.I updated my post

Comment: Can I know the reason for down votes.Is any wrong in that answer or any other things..?